# Issue with UV unwrapping

Tags: uv, vertices

I'm having an issue with UV unwrapping in Blender 2.90. I'm a beginner and this my first unwrapping. The vertices on UV Map are goes in infinite out of the UV image area, i don't have double vertex and the scale is applied, I didn't understood where is the problem, that's way I'm asking if some one could help me.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello :). Did you mark enough seams? Or try the automatic unwrap *UV > Smart UV project*

Comment: Thank you a lot! Solved by adding seams and then Smart UV project!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the answer! Solved by using UV > Smart UV Project that create an automatic seams, it is perfect method for this object.
[image]

Comment: Glad you made it work :). Just to clear it up - *Smart UV project* ignores manual seams, they're only used for manual unwrap :).

Comment: I got it! Thank you a lot for your explanation! I didn't know it.